# Почему падает браузер?

Tags: javascript

Почему при написании этого кода в консоль у меня падает браузер?

```
function duplicate(a)
{
if(Array.isArray(a)){
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            a.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
return a;
};
duplicate([1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: цикл никогда не закончится т.к. каждую итерацию `a.length` становится больше на 1

Comment: Потому что, увеличивая размер массива в каждой итерации цикла, цикл никогда не сможет дойти до конца массива.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что длина массива увеличивается с каждым выполнением `push`, а значит цикл бесконечный. Ну и рано или поздно доступная память закончится, и вкладка упадёт. Чтобы работало правильно, надо просто сохранить начальную длину в переменную:

```js
function duplicate(a) {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
      a.push(a[i]);
    }
  }

  return a;
}

console.log(duplicate([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: @andreymal, бывает)))